# Tkinter window goes "Not Responding" when writing csv file data from another csv file, but process running on background

Tags: python-3.x, csv, tkinter

Steps:

1. Reading CSV file (size = 30mb)
2. Writing to new CSV file based on search results
3. Process running in the background but the window says "Not Responding"

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We can't debug code that we can't see.

Comment: I am receiving output file but meantime window goes Not Responding,so I am looking for suggestions to avoid that.

Comment: The generic answer is to run the process in the background. Since you claim you're doing that, either you aren't, or you're doing it wrong. Without seeing your code we really have no idea what you mean by "in the background".